# Meaning of "hound"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across this sentence:

> "He believed that whatever he planned to do was hound to end in failure."

I looked up the meaning of the word "hound" in my dictionary. But either the word in this sentence is specific, or I didn't understand it. In any case, I would appreciate If you could explain it to me.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the original sentence. It should be "...was **bound** to end ..."

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. The letter "b" is always mistyped in the book I'm reading. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographical error.

Comment: @ choster: I wouldn't know it was a typo, if IconDaemon hadn't pointed to that; I would have continued searching for the meaning of "hound".

Comment: funny typo though =)
picturing that poor ending in failure hound...

Comment: @Rossitten: That's the main reason that pushed me to ask the question and submit here.

Answer (score 1):

hound (noun) is "a dog", or hound (verb in the infinitive) is "to pursue relentlessly". Neither makes sense here.  As IconDaemon has mentioned in a comment, it can only be a misprint, where an "h" was typed instead of a "b".

> bound to -  very likely, sure. ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bound)), predetermined; certain ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bound))

"He believed that whatever he planned to do was bound to end in failure." (was sure to end in failure, would probably end in failure)

Comment: Thank you. Because I read it "hound", explanations of my dictionary didn't stick. But thanks to IconDaemon, now they do.